# Как сделать задержку итерации цикла for или while?

Tags: c++

**Цель: Вывод строки в консоли с задержкой после каждого символа.**

Казалось бы все просто, однако при выполнении программы временная задержка в блоке FOR выполняется суммарно. Т.е. программа ждет когда внутри блока FOR или WHILE пройдут все итерации, и затем выводит строку одним разом.

пример

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::this_thread;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    string str = "Привет, я хочу чтобы ты ответила на несколько вопросов.";

    for (int l = 0; l < str.length(); l++) {

        cout << str[l];
        sleep_for(nanoseconds(10000000));
    }
}
```

Пробовал выделять памать для **str** динамически, но результат тот же. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А какой компилятор используете? В VS 2017 поведение соответствует ожидаемому.

Comment: Вы хотите медленный вывод? добавьте `cout.flush()` после `cout << str[l];` (хотя, например, VC++ работает и так...) Потом, немного рандомизируйте задержку, строку сделайте типа `"Привет, я хочу чтобы ты\b \b\bвы ответила\bи на несколько вопросов.";` - и будет ностальгический чат на бибиэсках (кто помнит такое чудо начала 90-х...:))

Comment: @Anamnian g++ 7

Comment: @Harry хм, этот вариант не сработал. Видимо зависит от компилятора. Хотя подобное поведение очень интересно.

Comment: @Harry спасибо прочитал про то как работает буферизация и о cout.flush(); Помогло

Comment: странно, но выполнив этот код получилось ровно то, что требуется, то символы через 10000000 наносекундными интервалами выводились а не сразу

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в буферизации

```
cerr << str[l];
```

Comment: да, cerr выводит с задержкой, правда не по одному символу а группами по 3-4. Подскажите, где можно прочитать больше про эту проблему или о буферизации в целом

Comment: предлагаю просто использовать английские символы)
"проблема" буферизации в том, что cout сначала пишет символы в буфер, а уже потом пачкой выводит в консоль, т.к. это более эффективно

Comment: спасибо прочитал про то как работает буферизация и о cout.flush(); Помогло